# Li items not showing properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

I'm using flexslider and it seems that the slider isn't working properly. The Li items is not working properly, it's not showing?

Here's my code.

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta content="charset=utf-8">
    <title>FlexSlider 2</title>
  <!-- Demo CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <!-- Modernizr -->
  <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
  <style>

  img {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  }
    img:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: gray;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
   transition: all 0.3s linear;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="images/stark.png" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/ad.png" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/ad.png" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/ad.png" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

  <!-- FlexSlider -->
  <script defer src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5
  });
});
        pausePlay: true,
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>


  <!-- Syntax Highlighter -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shCore.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shBrushXml.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shBrushJScript.js"></script>

  <!-- Optional FlexSlider Additions -->
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
  <script defer src="js/demo.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

It's on a separate html file, i'll just add an iframe on my main one to show it on my advertisement box. Hope you can help me with this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove som redundant closing `})` here:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
        itemWidth: 210,
        itemMargin: 5
    // }); <-- Here
// }); <-- Here
        pausePlay: true,
        start: function(slider){
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }); // <-- Add closing ) for start() function
    });
});
```